# Can we use regular expression to mention cucumber options feature files?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/module*.feature"},
tags = "@E2e",)
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.features=”module*.feature” -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@E2E"

Is there any way to use regex to identify feature files? It takes it up as file name.
I want moduleone,moduletwo,modulethree to get executed.

PS: I am aware about tags but my logic is in such a way that using feature regex will help me.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You can not. You can only reference files or directories. Patterns are not supported.